# nohup command running csh stop while I disconnect the ssh

Tags: ssh, nohup

Here is my `csh` to download atmospheric re-analysis data in National Center of Environmental Prediction(NCEP).

I upload my .csh file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQb0dIYkRaY3Qwemc/view?usp=sharing) to download files automatically in Linux cluster using code as:
`nohup ./2015.csh lpkcp19890702 &`

It was executed well in ssh mode. However, while I choose to quit the ssh connecting to the cluster using **exit** or **ctrl+D**, the program would stop.

What's wrong with my nohup setting. My linux cluster was just re-installed the whole system. Before the old system crashed, the `nohup`   command worked well in the background when I quit the connect.

Any advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Are you using [systemd 230+](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394)?

Comment: My system is CentOS release 5.9 (Final)